# Как вывести массив объектов на страницу списком в JS?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Помогите, пожалуйста правильно вывести массив объектов на страницу. В forEach зацикливает, вне не видны li

```
const flowers = [
  { 
    author: "Белі Свім",
    name: "Троянда",
    price: 60 
  }, 
  {
   author: "Джеймс Лоррі",
   name: "Тюльпан"
  }
]

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'root';

function flowerList(arr) {
    let ul = document.createElement('ul');
    books.forEach(elems => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        let list =
            (li.textContent = `author: ${elems.author}; name: ${elems.name}; price: ${elems.price}`);
        //console.log(li);
        ul.append(li);
        console.log(ul);
    });
    return;
}

flowerList(flowers);

document.getElementById('root').append(ul);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде есть несколько ошибок. Вот исправленный код:

```js
const flowers = [
  { 
    author: "Белі Свім",
    name: "Троянда",
    price: 60 
  }, 
  {
   author: "Джеймс Лоррі",
   name: "Тюльпан"
  }
]

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'root';
document.body.append(div); // добавляем div на страницу

function flowersList(arr) {
  let ul = document.createElement('ul');
  arr.forEach(elems => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = `author: ${elems.author}; name: ${elems.name}; price: ${elems.price}`;
    ul.append(li);
  });
  return ul; // возвращаем список
}

let flowersUl = flowersList(flowers); // получаем список цветов
document.getElementById('root').append(flowersUl); // добавляем список на страницу в div с id=root
```

В этом коде мы сначала создаем элемент `div`, добавляем его на страницу, потом определяем функцию `flowersList`, которая принимает массив объектов и возвращает список (`ul`) со списком цветов. В функции `flowersList` мы используем метод `forEach`, чтобы пройти по каждому объекту массива и создать `li` элемент для каждого цветка. Затем мы добавляем каждый `li` элемент в `ul`, а возвращаем `ul`. В главной функции мы вызываем `flowersList`, чтобы получить `ul`, и добавляем его на страницу в `div` с `id=root`.

Comment: помогите, пожалуйста еще вывести в консоль ошибку с текстом какого свойства не хватает, используя try catch

Comment: что? вы можете задать еще один вопрос, приложите код и ошбку

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1497727/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-try-catch