# Как вывести ошибку с недостающим свойством в объекте с помощью try catch?

Tags: javascript, массивы, try-catch

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться почему не работает catch и вывести ошибку с недостающим свойством:

```js
const flowers = [{
    author: "Белі Свім",
    name: "Троянда",
    price: 60
  },
  {
    author: "Джеймс Лоррі",
    name: "Тюльпан"
  },
  {
    name: "Нарцис",
    price: 45
  }
]

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'root';
document.body.append(div);

function flowersList(arr) {
  let ul = document.createElement('ul');
  arr.forEach(elems => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = `author: ${elems.author}; name: ${elems.name}; price: ${elems.price}`;
    try {
      //debugger;
      if (elems.author && elems.name && elems.price) {
        ul.append(li);
      } else {
        throw new Error();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      //console.log('work catch');
    }

  });
  return ul;
}

let flowersUl = flowersList(flowers);
document.getElementById('root').append(flowersUl);
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что `catch` не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема возникает из-за того, что внутри блока try-catch выбрасывается ошибка, когда какое-то из свойств объекта отсутствует, но не указывается текст ошибки, который будет передан в блок catch.

Для того чтобы вывести ошибку с недостающим свойством, можно в блоке catch создать новый объект ошибки и добавить в его свойство message текст ошибки, который вы можете определить вручную, указав отсутствующее свойство.

```
function flowersList(arr) {
  let ul = document.createElement('ul');
  arr.forEach(elems => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = `author: ${elems.author}; name: ${elems.name}; price: ${elems.price}`;
    try {
      if (elems.author && elems.name && elems.price) {
        ul.append(li);
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Отсутствует свойство: ${!elems.author ? 'author' : !elems.name ? 'name' : 'price'}`);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  });
  return ul;
}
```

В этом коде, если одно из свойств отсутствует, вы создадите новый объект ошибки с текстом, указывающим недостающее свойство, и передадите его в блок catch для вывода.

Например, если объект цветов `flowers` не содержит свойства author, то вы получите следующее сообщение об ошибке: `Отсутствует свойство: author`.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу еще один вариант решения. Лично я люблю универсальность в подходе, поэтому предлагаю использовать `Proxy` объект который может предоставить информацию о том какое свойство читается и вовремя это обработать. Главный плюс этого метода то что его можно переносить из проекта в проект практически не меняя либо меняя под конкретные нужды но не нагружая при этом `try-catch` основную логику программы. Так же я заметил, что заполнения списка не происходило поэтому пофиксил этот момент в коде. Для наглядности я не вызываю ошибку а делаю вывод в консоль, для вызова ошибки нужно лишь расскоментировать соответсвующую строку.

```js
const flowers = [{
    author: "Белі Свім",
    name: "Троянда",
    price: 60
  },
  {
    author: "Джеймс Лоррі",
    name: "Тюльпан"
  },
  {
    name: "Нарцис",
    price: 45
  }
]

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'root';
document.body.append(div);


function getProxy(obj){
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (prop in target) {
        return target[prop]
      } else {
        console.log(`Нет свойства: ${prop} в объекте ${JSON.stringify(target)}`)
        //throw new Error(`Нет свойства: ${prop} в объекте ${JSON.stringify(target)}`)
        return undefined        
      }
    }
  })
}

function flowersList(arr) {
  let ul = document.createElement('ul');
  arr.forEach(elem => {
    const prx =  getProxy(elem) // проксируем объект и далее обращаемся через прокси
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = `author: ${prx.author}; name: ${prx.name}; price: ${prx.price}`;
    ul.appendChild(li) // <---- добавление в список
  });
  return ul;
}

document.querySelector('#root').appendChild(flowersList(flowers))
```